# How can I do a time-weighted average of dataframe columns?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to do a weighted time average on this dataframe:

```
        Time             x    y
0   2020-10-30 18:00:00  1  265.0   
1   2020-10-30 18:00:00  2  265.0   
2   2020-10-30 18:12:00  5  263.5   
3   2020-10-30 18:12:00  4  412.0   
4   2020-10-30 18:12:00  3  412.0
```

So, basically Im trying that:

- for the rows with same 'Time' value do (x * y)
- sum all those multiplications: sum = (x1 * y1) + (x2 * y2) + ...
- divide them by the sum of all x values for that 'Time' value: sum / (x1 + x2 + ...)

In this case:

```
        Time             sum  weighted_avg_y
0   2020-10-30 18:00:00   3      265.0      
1   2020-10-30 18:12:00   12      350
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can first multiply the values in x and y, then `groupby` Time, and calculate the `sum` for the previous producct and x column, finally reset the index. Then you can just `divide` the product column by x column.

```py
out = (df.assign(product=df['x'].mul(df['y'])).groupby('Time')[['product', 'x']]
       .sum()
       .reset_index()
       )
out['weighted_avg_y'] = out['product']/out['x']
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
                  Time  product   x  weighted_avg_y
0  2020-10-30 18:00:00    795.0   3         265.000
1  2020-10-30 18:12:00   4201.5  12         350.125
```

You can rename the column `x` to `sum` and drop the column `product` if you want to.